# PWA - is it possible to open a native app from a PWA?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have a native app (requires functionality of a native app) but my site is now a PWA. Is there a way I can open my native app via a button in my PWA?

Comment: Nope. It is not possible for a web browser to send commands to the OS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can open native app via PWA. 
However, there will be no data connection between your native app and PWA.

In your PWA side, you just need to execute the code below when the button is clicked.

For iOS:

```
document.location.href = 'your_app_schemes_url://';
```

For Android:

```
document.location.href = 'intent:#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=app_package;end;';
```

Comment: In my Android PWA, this code opens the Google Play page of the target App. It'a a good solution to sigest installing the App, but it does not LAUNCH the app. Am i missing any thing or using a wrong appId?

Answer (score 0):

this works for Android:

```
document.location.href = `google.navigation://?q=${lat},${lon}`;
```